# How to use TETRAHEDRAL INTERPOLATION in 3d LUT?

Tags: c, image, video, linear-algebra, lookup-tables

I am make some practice in the image processing.
I try the trilinear interpolation and tetrahedral interpolation in 3DLUT image style transformation.
According to some papers, the image quality of tetrahedral interpolation should be better, especially when using 17 * 17 * 17 LUT table.
While to my surprise, my new image generated with tetrahedral seems not good as trilinear.
I guess that my understanding of tetrahedral interpolation is not correct.

Trilinear interpolation is relative easy, I just describe how I make the tetrahedral interpolation. Hopefully some image processing experts can kindly help me.

1. The same as trilinear, get the floor_R, floor_G, floor_B and delta_R, delta_G, delta_B;
2. Since the sub-cube is divided in to 6 tetrahedrals,  we need to decide which tetrahedral the target point should be inside. sort by size of delta_R, delta_G, delta_B and choose the suitable tetrahedral.  For example, if delta_B > delta_R > delta_G, then the target point should be in t1; if delta_B > delta_G > delta_R, then the target point should be in t2;....
3. Get the suitable tetrahedral, and get the 4 points R G B value  of the tetrahedrals.
4. Calculate the weight of 4 points of the tetrahedrals according to Euclidean distance from the target point to the 4 points of the tetrahedral.
5. Calculate the RGB of target point using the 4 weights and 4 points of the tetrahedral.

Then I find that image quality of tetrahedral interpolation is not as good as trilinear interpolation.  Trilinear use around 6 points, while tetrahedral only use around 4 points, theoretically tetrahedral should be worse, right? It seems my understanding of tetrahedral interpolation is not correct.

Can someone kindly help me check the my procedure of tetrahedral interpolation?

```
 //  get the R B G Floor and Fraction.
    Pixel* p = &pixels[i];

    float r = p->r / 255.0f * (LUTSize - 1);
    float g = p->g / 255.0f * (LUTSize - 1);
    float b = p->b / 255.0f * (LUTSize - 1);

    int rFloor = (int)floor(r);
    int gFloor = (int)floor(g);
    int bFloor = (int)floor(b);

    float fracR = r - rFloor;
    float fracG = g - gFloor;
    float fracB = b - bFloor;

     //define a tetrahedral to get the 4 points RGB coordination 
    int tetrahedral[4][3];  
    tetrahedral[0][0] = 0;
    tetrahedral[0][1] = 0;
    tetrahedral[0][2] = 0;
    tetrahedral[3][0] = 1;
    tetrahedral[3][1] = 1;
    tetrahedral[3][2] = 1;
    // choose a tetrahedral  from six tetrahedrals in the cube
    if ((fracB > fracR) && (fracR > fracG))  // t1
    {
        tetrahedral[1][0] = 0;
        tetrahedral[1][1] = 0;
        tetrahedral[1][2] = 1;

        tetrahedral[2][0] = 1;
        tetrahedral[2][1] = 0;
        tetrahedral[2][2] = 1;
    }
    else if ((fracB > fracG) && (fracG > fracR))  //t2 
    {
        .....  //similar code as above condition
    }
    else  ...                                       // until t6  G>R>B 

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        distance[i] = calOuDistance(fracR, fracG, fracB, tetrahedral[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        wight[i] = distance[i] / (distance[0] + distance[1] + distance[2] + distance[3]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        newindexB = bFloor + tetrahedral[i][2];
        newindexG = ...;
        newindexR = ...;

        newR += (float)lut_data[newindexB][newindexG][newindexR][0] * wight[i];
        newG += ...;
        newB += ...;
    }
    // get new R G B
    newR = newR * 255.0f;
    newG = ..
    newB = ..
```

Here are the images, using 17*17*17 3DLUT.

[this is original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FmX1.jpg)

[this is image generated by tetrahedral, some colors noise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9JNM.jpg)

[this is image generated by tr-linear, no obvious error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Wxe6.jpg)

Comment: well,I check my code, there is a bug of lut table overflow.  I fixed it. Now the color noises are gone.  But I don't find that tetrahedral is better than trilinear. So my question remains. Are there any expert kindly check my step?

Comment: Hi，@chux-ReinstateMonica   I add the sample code. Thanks.

Comment: Minor: rather than `int rFloor = (int)floor(r);  float fracR = r - rFloor;`, consider `float ipart; float fracR = modff(r, &ipart);`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica thank you for your suggestion.  you are right that I need to use modff to avoid potential precision issues.  What I mean is, it seems the computational cost of  tetrahedral interpolation is not larger than trilinear interpolation, and the image quality after interpolation  seems no obvious better(or maybe a little worse, bcause trilinear uses 6 points while tetrahedral only use 4 points).     But when I see some paper, they said that tetrahedral  is a good way to improve the quality.  So I am confused now.  Maybe my implementation of tetrahedral  is not correct?

Comment: charlie-xue, Interesting question, even though I am not family with the details of this interpolation.

Comment: There are a couple of reasons tetrahedral is "better" if the right segmentation is used where the common vertex of all six tetrahedra is (0,0,0) -> (1,1,1) "In an RGB space, this diagonal contains the neutral (or gray) colors, which are particularly important." - https://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2006/11/24/tetrahedral-interpolation-for-colorspace-conversion/. Tetrahedral uses less vertices (resulting in a reduction in memory bandwidth use) but it's using four vertices closest to the point of interest, so you shouldn't assume more vertices is better.

Comment: This is also useful as it explains some additional optimizations based on caching intermediate computational results for each cube or tetrahedron within the LUT.
https://community.acescentral.com/uploads/default/original/2X/5/518c5ede1ca11c4a7e13f9c7350e2228bb8762c7.pdf
There's also an example here with another link containing an explanation:
https://github.com/rigaya/NVEnc/blob/master/NVEncCore/NVEncFilterColorspaceFunc.h.
IMO the best way to debug this issue is to run the interpolation stand alone against a known linear function rather than looking at an image to see if it looks correct.